# getting back to bottom most line after moving a visual selection in vim

Tags: vim

I often make a visual selection in vim to shift right/left lines of code. Vim always puts me at the TOP most line after the shift. **What I want is an easy way to get to the BOTTOM most line. Is there a way to do this?**

For example

```
# before
  puts 'hello'
puts 'oops i messed up     # visual select to indent
puts 'and need to indent'  # visual select to indent
puts 'these three lines'   # visual select to indent

# after
  puts 'hello'
  puts 'oops i messed up    # cursor ends up here
  puts 'and need to indent'
  puts 'these three lines'  # but i want it here
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
`>
```

The `'>` mark will be put at the end of the last visual selection

Comment: Perfect! Now I just need to make it muscle memory

Comment: Can't make it work (Gvim in Windows). What is the help entry for that ?

Comment: Here is the documentation: `:h '>`. You may also want to look this section of the documentation as well: `:h mark-motions`.

Answer (score 1):

When you have a visual selection of lines, the <kbd>o</kbd> will jump from the top to the bottom and back.

If you have a visual block, <kbd>o</kbd> jumps from the top-left to the bottom-right, and back.

Comment: Sorry, I should have made it clearer in my question but I want to get to the bottom line AFTER the shift. I tried this but AFTER you shift left/right the cursor always goes back to the top.

Comment: I can't duplicate what you're seeing. If I shift text my cursor always stays where it was when I started. That's using MacVim and vim on Linux.

Comment: I tried on macvim and vim on mac osx and didn't work. Thought it might be my .vimrc so also tried on a brand new ubuntu 10.04 install with vim but none work. I actually like this solution better (less keystrokes) but unfortunately it doesn't work for me.

Comment: I should clarify that I am using `>>` and `<<` to "shift" visual blocks left/right.

Comment: Yes, `>>` and `<<`  are the standard way, which I use also. I will try to remember to check my .vimrc when I am at my computer, but I don't remember changing anything for shifting text.